# Facing issue with Camera in Xamarin iOS 13

Tags: xamarin.ios

**await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();**

This method throws an exception like the **Specified method is not supported.**

So unable to launch camera due to this problem.

Comment: are you testing on a device or using the simulator?

Comment: @Jason I am testing on it Simulator.

Comment: the simulator does not have camera functionality

Comment: yes..Thanks @Jason